# Minimum PC requirements to run latest Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, uninstall

I am FAR from any sort of expert in any type of Linux development.

I am looking to get an INEXPENSIVE and refurbished PC to run the latest release, but DO NOT want to cripple myself too much. It would be used mainly for browsing, word processing, audio listening, and video viewing. If there was some sort of Agent release I could run, I'd use it for that too.

Can someone help this self-diagnosed hardware moron to understand what processor (Core Duo 2?), etc. would give me a DECENT (not "stellar")Linux experience?

I'd appreciate any help VERY MUCH!!! :)

Sorry for all the caps... having a bad day, and why should you suffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, there are system requirements, but I believe those are mostly a formality. There's nothing really I can find for 16.04, but I've seen recommendations for something close to the following (64-bit):

- 2-3GB RAM
- 6GB HDD space (this you'll actually need to follow, but I doubt there will be any issue)
- 1GHz CPU
- 1024x768 display

Those specs are pretty low, but even if you can match them, don't worry. Ubuntu can run on pretty much anything that's got a 32-bit or 64-bit CPU. A computer from 2001 could run just fine (though I wouldn't recommend buying one).

For comparison, as long as it can run Windows 2000 or even earlier versions of NT, it'll run Ubuntu at least adequately. I recommend you get something a little more current than the mid-1990s, though. Maybe 2007?